# Using input/output structs in GLSL-Shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl, hlsl2glsl

In HLSL I can write:

```
struct vertex_in
{
    float3 pos    : POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float2 tex    : TEXCOORD;
};
```

and use this struct as an input of a vertex shader:

```
vertex_out VS(vertex_in v) { ... }
```

Is there something similar in GLSL?  Or do I need to write something like:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec4 aPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 aNormal;
...
```

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for are known as [***interface blocks***](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Interface_Block_%28GLSL%29) in GLSL.

Unfortunately, they are not supported for the **input** to the Vertex Shader stage or for the **output** from the Fragment Shader stage. Those must have explicitly bound data locations at program link-time (or they will be automatically assigned, and you can query them later).

Regarding the use of HLSL semantics like `: POSITION`, `: NORMAL`, `: TEXCOORD`, *modern* GLSL does not have anything like that. Vertex attributes are bound to a generic (numbered) location by name either using `glBindAttribLocation (...)` prior to linking or as in your example, `layout (location = ...)`.

For input / output *between* shader stages, that is matched entirely on the basis of variable / interface block name during GLSL program linking (except if you use the relatively new [Separate Shader Objects](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/separate_shader_objects.txt) extension). In no case will you have constant pre-defined named semantics like `POSITION`, `NORMAL`, etc. though; locations are all application- or linker-defined numbers.